# Flowplayer: Is there an equivalent for the html5 "timeupdate" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

This is my html5 approach:

```
bindProgressUpdate: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this.video).on('timeupdate', function() {
        var progressInPercent = self.video.currentTime / self.video.duration * 100;
        progressInPercent = Math.round(progressInPercent * 100) / 100;

        $(document).trigger('update_progress', [progressInPercent, self.video.currentTime, self.video.duration]);
    });
```

Now I am implementing an flashfallback that uses the same interface, so I need to reproduce the behaviour of the video-element. Yet flowplayer does not seem to fire anything remotely close to the `timeupdate` event.

Is there anything like it there, or do I have to set up my own interval in the background?